# Button Groups for Devise /shared/_links.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, devise, view

I have devise forms using bootstrap.

I like to get the buttons on shared/_links.html.erb to group together.

```
<div class="button-group btn-group-xs" role="group">
    <%- if controller_name != 'sessions' %>
        <%= button_to "Log in", new_session_path(resource_name), :class => 'btn btn-default', :type => 'button', :method => :get %>
    <% end -%>

    <%- if devise_mapping.registerable? && controller_name != 'registrations' %>
        <%= button_to "Sign up", new_registration_path(resource_name), :class => 'btn btn-default', :type => 'button', :method => :get %>
    <% end -%>

    <%- if devise_mapping.recoverable? && controller_name != 'passwords' && controller_name != 'registrations' %>
        <%= button_to "Forgot your password?", new_password_path(resource_name), :class => 'btn btn-default', :type => 'button', :method => :get %>
    <% end -%>

    <%- if devise_mapping.confirmable? && controller_name != 'confirmations' %>
        <%= button_to "Didn't receive confirmation instructions?", new_confirmation_path(resource_name), :class => 'btn btn-default', :type => 'button', :method => :get %>
    <% end -%>

    <%- if devise_mapping.lockable? && resource_class.unlock_strategy_enabled?(:email) && controller_name != 'unlocks' %>
        <%= button_to "Didn't receive unlock instructions?", new_unlock_path(resource_name), :class => 'btn btn-default', :type => 'button', :method => :get %>
    <% end -%>

    <%- if devise_mapping.omniauthable? %>
        <%- resource_class.omniauth_providers.each do |provider| %>
            <%= button_to "Sign in with #{provider.to_s.titleize}", omniauth_authorize_path(resource_name, provider), :class => 'btn btn-default', :type => 'button', :method => :get %>
        <% end -%>
    <% end -%>
</div>
```

I get this as a result.

[image: Login Screen Devise]

I suspect it's because every button has a form tag. Is there a way I can fix this using only bootstrap?

```
<div class="col-md-12 control">
    <div style="border-top: 1px solid#888; padding-top:15px; font-size:85%" >
        <div class="button-group btn-group-xs" role="group">
            <form class="button_to" method="get" action="/users/sign_up"><input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Sign up" /></form>
            <form class="button_to" method="get" action="/users/password/new"><input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Forgot your password?" /></form>
            <form class="button_to" method="get" action="/users/confirmation/new"><input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Didn&#39;t receive confirmation instructions?" /></form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverted back to link_to

Removed

```
button_to
method="get"
```

Reverted Back

```
link_to
```

Rails adds form tags around the button_to fields causing alignment problems, by adding btn class to link_to it did show up as a button.